# Read JSON data in Angular JS script and use that data further in JS only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have searched it a lot , in all cases , they usually want to show it on HTML directly , but my purpose is to use the data in Angular JS only.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var url ;
    $http.get('/HomeAccessService-1/static/js/data.json').then(function(response) {
        url = response.data;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(url.data));
        });
    //var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/HomeAccessService-1/user/';
    var REST_SERVICE_URI = JSON.stringify(url.data);
    var factory = {
        fetchAllUsers: fetchAllUsers,
        createUser: createUser,
        updateUser:updateUser,
        deleteUser:deleteUser
    };

return factory;

    function fetchAllUsers() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while fetching Users');
                deferred.reject(errResponse);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I want to use this url data in other methods , the data is actually a REST API URL which i put in `data.json` file

```
{"data":"http://someotherip:8080/Service/user/"}
```

It  shows `object Object` when alert ,

I dont want to show it in HTML but to use the data in angular js methods.

Comment: try to alert inside function.

Comment: i dont want to alert , i am using alert just to see the value , the aim is to use the url value , which is coming object Object

Comment: store the response in $scope variable and use it anywhere within the JS .    $scope.url = response.data;

Comment: angular js a worst language ever

Answer (score 1):

Alert is showing up before your response reach. Put alert inside request promise. You will get the response. 
and use `json.stringify(response.data)` to make a json string

Comment: when i use var REST_SERVICE_URI = JSON.stringify(url.data); outside the http call , i get error in UI - Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: $http.get("./data/data.json").then(function(response){
            var data= response;

           console.log(data);        });

Answer (score 0):

You should call the alert inside the promise otherwise it will be undefined when you alert it,

```
  $http.get('/Service-1/static/js/data.json').then(function(response) {
        url = response.data;
        alert(JSON.stringify(url.data));
   });*/
```

Inorder to display the correct data, you should use **`JSON.stringify()`**

```
alert(JSON.stringify(url.data));
```

Comment: @anshulkatta use JSON.stringify as mentioned in the answer

Comment: ok it works , but how do i pass this to another variable let say var REST_SERVICE_URI and use it in other methods  inside that same angular js file ,

Comment: define a angular constant and assign the value and use it across the file

Comment: i am doing this - var url ;
 $http.get('/HomeAccessService-1/static/js/data.json').then(function(response) {
  url = response.data;
  alert(JSON.stringify(url.data));
  });
    //var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/HomeAccessService-1/user/';
 var REST_SERVICE_URI = JSON.stringify(url.data);

Comment: but getting REST_SERVICE_URI is not defined
    at Object.fetchAllUsers in chrome console

Comment: Iis it another get request ?

Comment: yes , i am getting the URL from the first http request , then use the response in all other http requests , the response is actually a REST Service URL , which i get from json file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137867/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-anshulkatta).

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the two things 
 1. Add `REST_SERVICE_URI = ..` instead of that alert statement OR
 2. Add those geturl call inside `fetchAllUsers` function and then do your next steps once you get `resopnse.data`

```
//// Add url part inside get response
var url;
var REST_SERVICE_URI;
$http.get('/HomeAccessService-1/static/js/data.json').then(function(response) {
    url = response.data;
    REST_SERVICE_URI = JSON.stringify(url.data);
});
...

//// OR do it in sync

function fetchAllUsers() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/HomeAccessService-1/static/js/data.json').then(function(response) {
      url = response.data;
      REST_SERVICE_URI = JSON.stringify(url.data);
      $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
          .then(
          function (response) {
              deferred.resolve(response.data);
          },
          function(errResponse){
              console.error('Error while fetching Users');
              deferred.reject(errResponse);
          }
      );
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: i am getting $scope is not defined

Comment: Did you added `$scope` as a dependency injection inside your code ?

Comment: Something like this--->  `app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { ... }]);`

Comment: Ok just saw your upadated questiom where you added `factory`. When you call `fetchAllUsers` that time you dont have that 'url'

Comment: correct , so what need to be done , i guess  i need to call synchronously only the first call ,i need it to be called and get data before

Comment: Exactly! You can do one of the two things 1. Add `REST_SERVICE_URI = ..` instead of that alert statement OR 2. add those geturl call inside `fetchAllUsers` function and then do your next steps once you get resopnse.dara

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.jsondata=json.stringify(response.data)
     console.log(jsondata.url);
```

take all the json in one javascript variable then travarse that using loop or variable like jsondata.url and use it in ur future api call.